# Generating random strings

Tags: strings, random, lua

I've created the following string manipulation function for randomizing my passed string in Lua:

```
require "string"
require "math"

math.randomseed( os.time() )

function string.random( self )
    local tTemporary, tNew = {}, {}
    if not self or self:len() < 5 then
        return nil
    end
    self:gsub( "%a", function( cChar )
            table.insert( tTemporary, cChar )
        end
    )
    for i = 1, #tTemporary, 1 do
        local iRandom = math.random(1, #tTemporary)
        tNew[i] = tTemporary[iRandom]
        table.remove( tTemporary, iRandom )
    end
    return table.concat(tNew, "   ")
end
```

Can this be optimized/more-randomised?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of points to consider:

- Calling your function `shuffle` instead of `random` would be a better name since that's really what it's doing.
- The extra intermediate tables aren't really necessary to perform the shuffle. A single table is enough and you can perform the shuffle in-place right on that table.
- Consider a better separation between the process of shuffling and how the input is stored. For example, if you have your shuffle function take a table instead then that function can be reused on any kind of data and not just strings.
- I would do away with the Hungarian notation and just drop the type prefix on the variable names. Remember Lua variables themselves doesn't have a type. If you later change what that variable refers to then the Hungarian notation becomes misleading.

So I would refactor your original code into two functions. Here's one possibility:

```
function shuffle(self)
  if type(self) ~= 'table' then return nil end

  for i = #self, 2, -1 do
    local randi = math.random(i)
    self[i], self[randi] = self[randi], self[i]
  end
  return self
end

function shuffle_words(str)
  local strtable = {}
  for each in str:gmatch("%a+") do
    table.insert(strtable, each)
  end
  return table.concat(shuffle(strtable), ' ')
end
```

Comment: `"%a+"` should be `"%a"`

Comment: This is just an example of course, it assumes the input string is a bunch of words delimited by whitespace. If you have a different set of constraints then yes you *should* change the regex pattern to fit your needs.